# Repurchase of domain in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I deleted one domain 10 days ago and now I want to purchase it back but its not showing in the available list of domains. 
When I opened www.my-domain-name.com it showed "This page is parked free, courtesy of Azure".
What this mean and how can I get my domain back?

Comment: this means you should contact their customer support

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to look over [what is appropriate to ask here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure support question. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact azure support.

Answer (score -1):

After your delete operation is complete, the domain is released from your subscription and available for anyone to purchase again. If the domain is not showing in the available list of domains now. It means that the domain has been purchased by others. To confirm it, you can also search the domain using [Godaddy](https://godaddy.com).

If the domain is owned by other people, you can't purchase it back from Azure.